# Predicting value of E(k,0) for Block cipher with random and secret key

Tags: block-cipher, pseudo-random-permutation

Some mode of operation of block ciphers rely on the fact that E(k,0) is an unpredictable value when k is random and secret (with 0 denoting the all-zero binary string). Why is this a reasonable assumption?

Comment: I would say that specifying just a single zero as ciphertext is really bad practice. Either you should specify $0^{n}$ or indeed $0^{\{n\}}$ to specify a block of zeros of width $n$, just $0$ really doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 2):

A block cipher, according to its design purpose, is assumed to be a [pseudorandom permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_permutation). This means when the key $k$ is chosen at random, $E(k,\cdot)$ can be viewed as a random permutation. Then, $E(k,0)$ is indistinguishable from a random value of the block length, hence unpredictable.

Comment: But what exactly does E(k,0) mean here? Does the all-zero binary string matter at all?

Comment: @kivi Good point :) Actually E(k,x) is unpredictable for any x if x is the first query to E(k,.).

Answer (score 0):

If $\pi$ is a uniform random permutation of $\ell$-bit strings, then $\pi(0)$ is a uniform random $\ell$-bit string.  (Similarly, the string $(\pi(0), \pi(1))$ is not uniformly distributed—it excludes the $2^\ell$ pairs of the form $(x, x)$—but it is very close.)

If you have a secure cryptosystem defined in terms of $\pi(0)$, and you instantiate it with $\pi = \operatorname{AES}_k$ where $k$ is a uniform random key, the fact that you're using a uniform random *AES* permutation instead of a uniform random permutation in general gives the adversary very little advantage in breaking the instantiation of the cryptosystem.  So even though $\operatorname{AES}_k(0)$ may not have exactly uniform distribution when $k$ is uniformly distributed, it is close enough as far as any algorithms we know can discern.